# Node JS and Nginx routing

Tags: node.js, nginx, routes

I'm having a little bit of trouble rerouting my server:80 to my node js app running in port 9999.

I have my nginx setup like so:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://principal-domain.com:9999/;
    }

    location ~/\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

But obviously only `/` is being rerouted. If I make a request to `/api` I get a 502 Bad Gateway.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Apply the rerouting for all routes in `mydomain.com`?

Comment: `location /` means _"all requests prefixed by /"_, so requests to `/api` get passed. However, your Node app is probably crashing, which is causing nginx to return the 502.

Comment: That was it thanks!